# Dynamic IIS hosted WCF Service with TCP binding

Tags: wcf, iis, dynamic, hosting, nettcpbinding

I am using Dynamic IIS Hosting (http://blog.micic.ch/net/dynamic-iis-hosted-wcf-service) with http binding. How can I use tcpbinding with dynamic IIS hosting.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are experiencing problems with registration VirtualPathProvider on start up using non-HTTP activation, you should put class with any name to App_Code folder. This class must have `public static void AppInitialize()` method, where you can register VirtualPathProvider.

```
namespace YourHostNameSpace.App_Code
{
    public class NonHttpActivation
    {
        public static void AppInitialize()
        {
             //do start up stuff here
        }
    }
}
```

By the way, WCF 4 provides file-less functionality out of the box on top WCF 4 Routing.

Comment: in Global.asax on App_Start I use HostingEnvironment.RegisterVirtualPathProvider(new ServicePathProvider()); what should I use in this metod

Comment: Well, I think the best option is to use WCF 4 routing. Then you should write RouteTable.Routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("Data", new ServiceHostFactory(), typeof(DataDips))); in this method

Comment: And don't forget add this section to config <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true">
  <serviceActivations>
    <add relativeAddress="Data.svc" service="DataDips" />
  </serviceActivations>
</serviceHostingEnvironment>

Comment: raise error.The name 'RouteTable' does not exist in the current context

Comment: if you want to see project, I can send project to you.

Comment: Ok. I do that. I used AppInitialize instead of Global.asax. But I run the service. Service address is http://localhost:31255/ ... when I request httprequest . fine but when I request tcp request. does not work